# IIS - Setting physical path gives 503 status for a few seconds

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I'm working on deploying a .NET Core website via Azure Devops to Windows / IIS 10. The flow goes like this:

1. Unzip the artifact to folder X
2. Transform XML and JSON files in that folder X
3. Update physical path of a IIS website to folder X

For some reason, setting physical path makes the website return `503 Service Unavailable` for a few seconds. The same goes if I just change physical path via the IIS GUI. So, after physical path is set, the following happens:

1. For ~2 seconds, the website returns 503.
2. For ~20 seconds, the request is on hold...
3. ... until IIS returns valid HTML content.

Is there a way to make IIS hold the requests rather than returning 503 for those initial 2 seconds?

Not sure if [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41340) is related.

Comment: It is not feasible to expect IIS will be always on when you completely change the bits in web content folder. The web app needs to be re-initialized so 503 is by design. You can search via keywords like "zero downtime ASP.NET Core" to learn more. Possible options are out there.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your answer. I just have a hard time seing a scenario where anyone actually wants 503 results rather than waiting for the request to be handled. It may be by design, but in my mind, that design is unwanted.

Comment: The designer of a single server (like IIS, nginx) shouldn't waste too much time on the  zero downtime scenario as that can be easily resolved with add-ons or better high availability solutions like load balancer. If you later read more about high availability design, you will see a single server is doomed to be unreliable.